# how to trigger a async process one after another

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

How I should modify the following code, so I can make sure Process3 is triggered after Process2.update or Process2.create completed?
The main purpose for following code is I want to make
Process1 finished. Then check if id exist, if yes, Process2.update is triggered. if not, Process2.create is triggered.
Once Process2 finished, check if cmd existed. if yes,triggered Process3.

```
  run: function (req, res) {
    if (req.session) {
      const values = req.params.all();
      const id = values.id;
      const cmd = values.cmd;
      const param = _.omit(values, ['cmd', 'id']);

      const cb1 = (e, d) => {
        if (e) {
          console.log(e);
          res.status(400).send({ e });
        } else {
          Process1(values);
          res.status(200).send({ d });
        }
      };
      const cd2 = (id, param, cb1) => {
        if (id) {
            Process2.update({ id }, param, cb1);
        } else {
            Process2.create(param, cb1);
        }
      };

      if (cmd) {
        cd2(id, param, cb1, Process3(values, cmd));
      }
      else {
        cd2(id, param, cb1);
      }

    } else {
      res.status(403).send({ e: 'Forbidden access.' });
    }
  }
```

try approach by following, but not sure how I can pass argument id, params to Process2 and process3

```
let async = require('async');
const Process1 = (value, cb) => {
    console.log("Process1()");
    console.log(value);
    cb(null, value + 1);
};
const Process2 = (value, cb) => {
    console.log("value(): wait 5 sec");
    console.log(value);
    cb(null, value+10);
};
const Process3 = (value, cb) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log("Process3(): wait 5 sec");
    cb(null, value+100);
};
let Pro_1_2 = async.compose(Process2, Process1);
let Pro_2_3 = async.compose(Process3, Process2);
Pro_1_2(1, (e, r) => {
    Pro_2_3(r, (error, result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: `Process1, 2, 3` are async functions? They return promise?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using "[compose](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#compose)", from async.js?

```
const a = (data, cb) => {
  var result = 'a';
  cb(null, result);
};
const b = (data, id, cb) => {
  var result = 'b';
  cb(null, result);
};
const c = (data, cb) => {
  // stuff to do with result
};

var aThenC = async.compose(c, a);
var bThenC = async.compose(c, b);

if (useA) {
  aThenC(data, (result) => {
    // result from c
    res.status(200).send(result);
  });
} else {
  bThenC(data, id, (result) => {
    // result from c
    res.status(200).send(result);
  });
}
```

In this scenario, **a** and **b** are your Process2 create and update, respectively, and **c** is the callback to Process3, if I understood correctly.

**EDIT:** You'll only have to enter the initial parameters (e.g. register ID) on the composed function. What composes really do is this: a(b(c(param))). That param is basically everything you need to start the process. The parameters for the following functions will be set inside the function before that.

*I'll add code to support it as soon as I'm on a keyboard.*

Comment: what I really want is Process 1 run first. Once it finished, Process2.update or Process2.create run depend on if id exist. Once Process2 finished, Process3 run if cmd exist

Comment: @jacobcan118 Well, you can, then, use a similar approach with compose, too, composing Process1 to Process2 create or update and then composing Process3, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in your original question seems pretty twisted up, so I'm not going to attempt to rewrite it, but in general if you want to perform asynchronous calls which depend on each other, [`async.auto`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#auto) is a good way to go.  Rather than declaring variables at the top that you attempt to mutate via some function calls, it's better to make `Process1`, `Process2` and `Process3` asynchronous functions that call their callbacks with a new `values` object.  Something like:

```
async.auto({

  doProcess1: function(cb) {
    // Assuming Process1 calls `cb(undefined, newValues)` when done.
    Process1(values, cb);
    return;
  },

  doProcess2: ['doProcess1', function(results, cb) {
    if (results.doProcess1.id) {
      Process2.update({id: results.doProcess1.id}, cb);
      return;
    } else {
      Process2.create(_.omit(results.doProcess1, ['cmd', 'id']), cb); 
      return;
    }
  }],

  doProcess3: ['doProcess2', function(results, cb) {
    if (results.doProcess2.cmd) { 
      Process3(results.doProcess2, cb);
      return;
    }
    else {
      cb(undefined, results.process2);
      return;
    }

  }]

}, function afterProcess3(err, results) {
  // Handler err or process final results.
});
```

Note all the `return` calls.  They're not strictly necessary, but good practice to avoid accidentally running more code after calling your asynchronous functions.